# GetTickCount on system running more than 49days

Tags: windows, winapi

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) GetTickCount API returns system elapsed time only if the system has not been running continuously for 49.7days. If its running more than that, it will return 0.

Anyone have any experience of such incident that this API actually returns 0 on systems, which is running more than 49.7 days?

I need to take some decision based on GetTickCount reported value and if I found 0 I will treat that as a special case and ask user for a system reboot.

Comment: You can use WMI or the 64-bit version of that API to bypass the limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not check for `0`; others have covered why that check is flawed. If you want to avoid the wraparound behavior, avoid `GetTickCount` altogether. Use `GetTickCount64`, or if you need to support pre-Vista systems, use [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which are both available as far back as Windows 2000.

For `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`, the returned value is measured in 100-nanosecond ticks since January 1, 1601, so you can convert to milliseconds like this:

```
DWORD64 MyGetTickCount64()
{
  FILETIME ft;
  GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
  DWORD64 ret = (DWORD64(ft.dwHighDateTime)<<32) | ft.dwLowDateTime;
  ret = ret / 10000;// convert to milliseconds.
  return ret;
}
```

[`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could be used like this:

```
DWORD64 MyGetTickCount64() {
  LARGE_INTEGER freq;
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
  LARGE_INTEGER now;
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&now);
  return now.QuadPart / freq.QuadPart * 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When the tick count rolls over, it goes back to `0` but continues counting. So you can get the following sequence of values: `4294967295`, `0`, `1`, `2` and so on. Contrary to your suspicions, the tick count does not roll over to `0` and then remain there forever more. The tick count continues counting upwards after it has rolled over.

Asking the user to reboot the machine because your program is not capable of counting past 2<sup>32</sup> seems a rather weak solution to the problem. You should solve the problem properly. Perhaps with `GetTickCount64`, or indeed some other measurement of time that does not roll over.

Comment: Another option if your application only deals with relative intervals below 50 days would be to rely on modular arithmetic, e.g. transforming `if(a < b)` into `if(a - b < 0)` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

No.

GetTickCount wraps around to 0 after 49.7 days, but as soon as it does, it starts counting up again.

You may want to use GetTickCount64 instead (it's been available since Vista). If you need to support older systems (and maybe even if you don't) you might want to use GetSystemTimeAsFileTime instead. This has been available nearly forever (officially listed as Windows 2000, but I think it may be even older than that).

Both of the latter use 64-bit counts, so rollover isn't a problem.